# Legendre transform preserves strict convexity

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, physics, mathematical-physics

Let $f:A\to \Bbb R$ be a strictly convex function of Class $C^2$ in a open and convex subset $A$ of $\Bbb R^n$.

Say that $g$ is its Legendre Transform defined as:
$g(p) = \max_{A} (xp - f(x))$
Say also that we already know $g’(p) = x(p)$ where $p = \nabla f(x(p))$.

How can I prove that $g$ is thus strictly convex?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of assumptions can be stripped from this. We don't require $f$ to be twice differentiable, or even strictly convex. I just want $f$ to be convex and differentiable.

If $g$ is not strictly convex, then there exist distinct points $y_1, y_2$ where
$$g\left(\frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}\right) = \frac{g(y_1)}{2} + \frac{g(y_2)}{2}.$$
Let $z$ maximise $z^\top \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} - f(z)$. That is
$$g\left(\frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}\right) = z^\top \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} - f(z) \ge x^\top \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} - f(x)$$
for all $x \in A$. This further means, from our assumption,
\begin{align*}
\frac{g(y_1)}{2} + \frac{g(y_2)}{2} &= z^\top \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2} - f(z) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(z^\top y_1 - f(z)) + \frac{1}{2}(z^\top y_1 - f(z)) \\
& \le \frac{g(y_1)}{2} + \frac{g(y_2)}{2},
\end{align*}
hence $z$ also maximises $z^\top y_i - f(z)$ for $i = 1, 2$.

Now, since
$$y_i^\top z - f(z) \ge y_i^\top x - f(x),$$
for all $x \in A$ and $i = 1, 2$, we then get
$$f(x) \ge y_i^\top x - y_i^\top z + f(z),$$
the right hand side of which is a pair of affine functions in $x$, each achieving the value $f(z)$ at $x = z$. The graphs of these affine functions would each be a tangent hyperplane to $f$ at $z$. But, the tangent hyperplane is unique ($f$ is assumed to be differentiable, and $z \in A$, where $A$ is open), so we have a contradiction.

Comment: This is really interesting. If I am not mistaken the Legendre transform of the Legendre transform of a convex $f$ is $f$ itself. By your theorem I think this means that any convex $f$ will be *strictly convex* as soon as its Legendre transform is differentiable.

Comment: @KurtG. That is true, but I absolutely cannot claim this result as my own. I don’t know who came up with it initially, but if the naming of this transformation and the concept of Legendre functions are anything to go by, it may well have been Legendre himself who first proved this result.

Answer (score 0):

The strict convexity of $f$ is equivalent to $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in A\,.$

The maximum in $g(p)=\max\limits_{x\in A}(xp-f(x))$ is attained for the unique  $x=x(p)$ that satisfies
$$\tag{1}
p=f'(x)\
$$
(do you know why that $x$ is unique?).
Therefore,
$$
g(p)=x(p)p-f(x(p))\,.
$$
It seems to me you are wrongly assuming $g(p)=x(p)$ instead.

To prove strict convexity of $g$ we only have to show $g''>0\,:$
Clearly,
$$
g'(p)=x'(p)p+x(p)-f'(x(p))x'(p)=x(p)
$$
by (1). Therefore, using $x(p)=(f')^{-1}(p)\,,$ and the derivative of the inverse function,
$$
g''(p)=x'(p)=\frac{1}{f''((f')^{-1}(p))}>0\,.
$$