# Legendre transform of uniformly convex smooth function is uniformly convex (Evans 3.4.5.)

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

In Evans' PDE chapter 3.4.5 in the proof of Theorem 5, the uniform convexity of the Legendre transformation $L=F^*$ is invoked, but I don't seem to be able to prove this. More specifically let $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function which is uniformly convex; i.e. $F''\geq \theta>0$ for a constant $\theta$. Let $L(v)=F^*(v)=
\sup_{p}(pv-F(p))$. Can it be shown that $L$ is uniformly convex?

I tried the following: For $G=(F')^{-1}$ we have
$L'(v)=G(v)$ so that
$$
L''(v)=G'(v)=\frac{1}{F''(G(v))},
$$
but I can't get a lower bound for this in terms of $\theta$.

EDIT: Nevermind. I just read Evans' errata of the book and there he adds the additional assumption for theorem 5 that $L=F^*$ need be smooth and uniformly convex. This theorem here about the Legendre transform being uniformly convex is probably  false. I guess this post should still stay up incase someone else is wondering about it?

Comment: Very closely [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4558155/949989).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need an upper bound on $F''$ to get a lower bound on $L''$. Uniform convexity of $F$ is not needed. Just for the record, here is a simple counterexample.
Let $X = \mathbb R$ and
$$
F(x) = \frac12 x^2 + |x|.$$
Then, one can check that
$$
L(x) = \frac12 \max\{0, |x|-1\}^2,$$
which is not uniformly convex.